# I want to run jade with angular module

Tags: angularjs, express, pug

This is my jade code:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        script(src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js")
        script(src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.min.js")
        script(href="../public/javascripts/app.js")
        link(href="../public/stylesheets/sample.css")       
        title my jade template
    body(ng-app='infonioninfo')
        h1 data loaded from json test
        #ngapp(ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax1")
            h2 {{posts}}
```

And this my angular code:

```
var infonionapp=angular.module('infonioninfo',['ngRoute','ngResource']);
```

I got error on browser

```
angular.js:36 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=infonioninfo&p1=Er…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.25%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387)
```

Comment: Where do you load angular-resource?

Comment: load in seperate file and i was included like this.. script(href="../public/javascripts/app.js") in jade file